# How to compile Excel VSTO-Workbook into the Excel file

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

Is it possible to compile Excel-VSTO workbook into the Excel-File itself?
This is my Project
[image]
[image]
But I want all the files compiled into the Excel file.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible because in order to enable a document-level VSTO customization the workbook [needs to have](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds87aeyf.aspx) an entry `_AssemblyLocation` in the `Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties`.

This entry has to contain the path to the .vsto file.
If you use ClickOnce it will look something like this:

```
file:///DeploymentServer/MaterialTable.vsto|74744e4b-e4d6-41eb-84f7-ad20346fe2d9
```

If you use your own Setup.exe to deploy all files locally instead, you can specify this local path as well by appending `vstolocal` to the end:

```
file:///C:/Program Files/MaterialTable/MaterialTable.vsto|74744e4b-e4d6-41eb-84f7-ad20346fe2d9|vstolocal
```

This .vsto file contains the related names of the .manifest and .dll files that Excel also needs to load.

So unfortunately you just can't compile a document-level VSTO customization into a workbook because Excel needs to have physical access to the .vsto/.manifest/.dll files.
But if you're using the `vstolocal` deployment, you can at least specify an absolute file path so that your .xlsx file doesn't need to be in the same directory as your .vsto/.manifest/.dll files. So maybe this could be (at least kind of) an alternative solution for your problem.